# AngularJS and listening to window events/messages

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to trigger an AngularJS controller function from a window event. However, $http() inside the function doesn't execute. It just stops.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(msg) {

    // this works!!
    alert(angular.element(document.getElementById('ListFindRooms')).scope().var);

    // this kinda works, but Angular $http() inside the funciton is not executed
    angular.element(document.getElementById('ListFindRooms')).scope().function();
}

});
```

Comment: I hope the function isn't really named `function` as that's a keyword...

Comment: Have you tried extracting the scope and calling the function in a `scope.$apply` block?

Comment: @Praveenram, can you please explain what you mean? I am new to Angular.

Comment: You can try `var element_scope=angular.element(document.getElementById('ListFindRooms')).scope(); element_scope.$apply(function () { element_scope.function_name(); });`. It runs the angular methods under the $apply, $digest cycle.

Comment: Link to scope documentation here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Here is a much better article on how to use $apply [http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: putting your listener inside a directive would give you access to the element itself and make situation a lot cleaner code wise

Comment: Thanks all. Praveenram your solution works. It might not be pretty seperation of dom and controllers, but for now it works. I'll refactor later. I can't mark a comment as answer...